# Proxy Error While Publishing to Intranet Confluence Page with Sphinx Confluence

Tags: python-sphinx, confluence

I am attempting to publish Sphinx documentation on an intranet Confluence page which has a server URL similar to the following: `https://DomainName.CompanyName.TopLevelDomain`

When I run `python -m sphinx -b confluence . /confluence -E -a` in the terminal, I enter my username and password and then get the following 403 proxy error:

```
sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder error:

---
Invalid Confluence URL detected

An issue has been detected when trying to communicate with the
configured Confluence instance. Ensure the instance is running and
inspect that the configured Confluence URL is valid:

   https://DomainName.CompanyName.TopLevelDomain

(details: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https://DomainName.CompanyName.TopLevelDomain', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/space?spaceKey=<MySpaceKey>&limit=1 (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'))))
```

---

I tried adding `confluence_proxy = 'http://my-proxy:port/'` to my `conf.py` and got the same error. How can I avoid the proxy error?